# What are some good apps for creating a family tree and researching your family's past?

Tags: webapp-rec

What are some good apps for creating a family tree and researching your family's past?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Geni.com](http://www.geni.com/)

Comment: Cool - was just thinking the other day that I should make a family tree - this seems to do the job... although sometimes the layout goes a bit wonky.

Comment: This site is so much fun!  Good way to make time go by a little faster on a super slow day at work... glad you posted it :) It seems so user friendly my Grandma could do it.

Comment: This site appears to allow you to create a family tree and if you subscribe will match to trees created by other users. No obvious facility for researching ancestors.

Answer (score 3):

[ancestry.com](http://www.ancestry.com)

Comment: This site allows you to create a family tree but will also let you research various census and other records for ancestors (site states that most historical records used are from between 1790 to 1930)

Answer (score 3):

[familysearch.org](http://www.familysearch.org/)

This site allows you to create a family tree but will also let you research various census and other records for ancestors

Answer (score 1):

[genesreunited.co.uk](http://www.genesreunited.co.uk/)

This site allows you to create a family tree and also lets you research various census and other records for your ancestors.

If another user has created a tree with people that match your tree then basic details are show in a 'Hot Matches' area. The more elements that match your tree (names, common relations, dates, etc...) the hotter the match.

Answer (score 0):

[Genlighten.com](http://genlighten.com)

Genlighten is a really neat site that connects those looking for family history with researchers who actually gather the data for them (sometimes physically, if necessary).